# Xcode cannot load extra libraries

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, glfw, glew

I am using macOS 10.15 and Xcode11.1 to do my OpenGL project. However, Xcode cannot build the program as errors was detected and the program crashed. It states:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rcpath/libGLEW.2.1.dylib
Referenced from:@rcpath/Xcode/DerivedData/GLFW_opengl-digmcjjsxnhrabepersfaxavutvh/Build/Products/Debug/GLFW opengl
Reason: no suitable image found.  
Did find: /usr/local/opt/glew/lib/libGLEW.2.1.dylib: 
code signature in (/usr/local/opt/glew/lib/libGLEW.2.1.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: 
mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
```

I have followed many tutorials online, brew installed the libraries and finished all the settings both in the Header search paths and Linked Binaries with Library. But it also fails to build.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your libGLEW is not code signed. Since MacOS Catalina, the code has to be at least ac-hoc signed.

You might download the newest version of libGLEW [here](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/releases) and see if it fixes. If that didn't help, you can compile it from [source](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/releases/download/glew-2.1.0/glew-2.1.0.zip). After that, all you have to do is replace your old libGLEW.dylib with the new one.